# Listener doesn't work if I pass a function from "this"

Tags: javascript, extjs

I ran into very strange behavior:

This code throws "TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined":

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    listeners: {
        close: this.processClose
    },
    processClose: function() {
        alert('processed');
    }
}).show();
```

But this works correctly

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    listeners: {
        close: function() {
             this.processClose();
        }
    },
    processClose: function() {
        alert('processed');
    }
}).show();
```

How is it possible ? It seems to me that these two pieces of code are completely the same.

Answer (score 3):

They are not the same. The difference is the time where `this` gets evaluated. In the first case, `this` will be pointing to whatever the `this` pointer is while making the declaration, because the whole right hand side needs to be evaluated before it can even create the window object. In the second case, it's deferred until the callback executes. In the case of the `close` event, the `this` pointer defaults to the window object.

Comment: It might be worth spending some time to understand how JavaScript scoping works.